# How to pass variable one file to another using f write function

Tags: php, html

Hi how to pass variables from one file to another file with f write

i have a file name a.php

code is

```
 <?php
       if(isset($_POST['psub'])){
           $myfile = fopen("an.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
           $pst = $_POST['pst'];
           fwrite($myfile,$pst);
           fclose($myfile);
       } 
 ?>
<form  action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="pst">
    <input type="submit" name="psub" value="submit">    
</form>
```

i need in an.php

```
$abc = "GET VALUE FROM $pst"
```

Comment: Haven't been in PHP for a while. But, can't you use `require_once` instead of `fopen` for this kind of purpose?

Comment: hi i just need like if submit value using from and i need submitted value in another file variable.

Comment: Inputs with type `submit` are rendered as buttons and do not truly pass a value on form submission. It looks like you should be checking for `$_POST['pst']`. Also I've no idea what use case this could be for - but whatever it is, be *very* wary of letting the user add arbitrary content to a file on your server!

Comment: Have your form's action point to `an.php` then?

Comment: `$pst = '<?php $abc="'.$_POST['pst'].'";';` though what your doing is unsafe.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you approach this the wrong way.

Add an.php as an action in your form in a.php and, if you need to, redirect back to it after processing needed data.

Your **a.php**:

```
<form  action="an.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="pst">
<input type="submit" name="psub" value="submit">
</form>
```

and your **an.php**:

```
if( isset($_POST['psub']) && isset($_POST['pst']) ){
    // do what you need with it
    $abc = "GET VALUE FROM $_POST['pst']";
}
// some other work that you need
header("Location : a.php");
```